# Why is the wait -n option not available on the latest Debian Wheezy and how can I fix this?

Tags: bash, debian

calling wait -n on my debian wheezy box yields an error.

calling help wait shows that this option is not available.

why is this and can I apt-get an updated wait command that includes the -n option?

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to upgrade to `bash` 4.3, which is the version that added the `-n` option to the `wait` built-in command.

Comment: can this be done without risking a larger surgery on my system?

Comment: If by that you mean "without upgrading `bash`", then no. `wait` is not an external command.

Comment: I googling for a way to upgrade bash through the apt system. Is this somehow possible? 4.3+ has arrived in post wheezy distros so I guess it should be possible?

Comment: I don't know. That's a different question, and off-topic for Stack Overflow.